# A natural example in category theory

Tags: category-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm looking for a *natural* example of a category $\mathcal{C}$ with finite limits (or just finite products) wherein some object $X$ is not isomorphic to a subobject of an inhabited object. In other words, $X$ is such that there is no $Y$ in $\mathcal{C}$ equipped with monomorphisms $1 \to Y$ and $X \to Y$. Kudos if the category is also regular.

I'm looking for a natural example of this that *could* occur in the mathematical wilderness. In other words, a category that a mathematician could encounter without actively looking for such a pathological example. The purpose is to give a concrete example of a regular category with finite limits that fails to have coproducts in a really pathological way.

Comment: Does the requirement given include the case where $Y$ is $X$ and the morphism $X \to Y$ is the identity, or must they be distinct?

Comment: This is not an explicit requirement but it is implied: if $X$ is itself inhabited then it is clearly isomorphic to a subobject of an inhabited object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider for example the category of sheaves (local homeomorphisms) over $S^1$ with *connected* total space.

Here the terminal object is (the identity of) $S^1$, and let $X:=\Bbb R$ with the standard (spiralic) cycling $\Bbb R\to S^1:\ \ x\mapsto e^{ix}$. If $X\subseteq Y$ is also a sheaf, and has a trivial section $S^1\to Y$, then $Y$ is not connected.

Comment: Oh! This is excellent! I think this has finite products but not all finite limits. Right?

Comment: Why is $Y$ not connected?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg If $Y$ is inhabited, it has to contain a circle $U$ as a trivial section, and this $U$ is a union of open subsets (as $Y\to S^1$ is local homeomorphism), so itself is open. Similarly, $X\subseteq Y$ also has to be open, and these must not intersect, again by the local homeomorphism property.